# What's wrong with my custom type for JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My custom type is (no default constructor!):

```
package com.XXX.common;
public class Email implements Serializable {
  private String e;
  public Email(String str) {
    e = str;
  }
}
```

My entity in Hibernate 3.5.6:

```
package com.XXX.persistence;
import com.XXX.common;
@Entity
@TypeDef(
  name = "email",
  defaultForType = Email.class,
  typeClass = Email.class
)
public class User {
  @Id private Integer id;
  @Type(type = "email")
  private Email email;
}
```

Hibernate says:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for:
com.XXX.common.Email, at table: user, for columns: 
[org.hibernate.mapping.Column(email)]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My custom type is (no default constructor!) (...)

A custom type must implement one of the interfaces from [`org.hibernate.usertype`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/usertype/package-frame.html) (implementing [`UserType`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html) would be enough for your specific example), your `Email` class is **NOT** a custom type. In other words, you'll need to create some `EmailType` class that Hibernate will use to persist a field or property of type `Email`.

PS: There is IMO not much value at wrapping a  `String` with a class but let's say it was an example.

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [5.2.3. Custom value types](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-custom)

#### Resources

- [Hibernate CompositeUserType and Annotations](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/hibernate_compositeusertype_and_annotations)
- [user_type examples on the Hibernate Wiki](http://community.jboss.org/en/hibernate?view=tags&tags=user_type)

Answer (score 4):

`typeClass` must point to something that extends `UserType` (this handler class contains the mapping from and to the database).